# Overriding Symfony Error page in dev mode

Tags: php, symfony, error-handling

I'm working on a Symfony Bundle in order to add an AI recommandation when an Exception occurs, in the debug page (dev. mode).

To do that, I have followed the Symfony Documentation and created a **custom controller** to handle Exception.

*This is a working example of the result* :

[image]

However, **this controller is not called** when other exception occurs, such as PHP Syntax errors :

[image]

I've tried to create multiple listeners on different events (kernel.exception for example), but none of them is called when this type of Exception (PHP syntax) occurs.

Do you know how can I collect and handle ALL exceptions that occurs to a Symfony project ?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

following up :

https://github.com/acseo/AIErrorExplainedBundle

This Bundle proposes to override the default ErrorHandler (in dev mode) to add AI recommandation to solve the encountered error.

it is in beta, feel free to install it, test it, and give me feedback about it

Answer (score 0):

Error pages for the production environment can be customized in different ways depending on your needs:

1. If you only want to change the contents and styles of the error pages to match the rest of your application, [override the default error templates](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/error_pages.html#overriding-the-default-error-templates);
2. If you want to change the contents of non-HTML error output, [create a new normalizer](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/error_pages.html#overriding-non-html-error-output);
3. If you also want to tweak the logic used by Symfony to generate error pages, [override the default error controller](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/error_pages.html#custom-error-controller);
4. If you need total control of exception handling to run your own logic use the [kernel.exception event](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/error_pages.html#use-kernel-exception-event).

This is the [default controller](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/6.2/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Controller/ErrorController.php) that you need to overwrite if you want to implement point 3.

This is the [sample code](https://inviqa.com/blog/guide-custom-error-handling-symfony) if you want to implement point 4

Comment: Thank you for your anwser ! As you can see in my first screenshot, I have succesfully overriden the default error controller, and it works for SOME error, not for all, such as Parse Errors.

Comment: Can you paste your controller code here? You can handle it with error code 500. `HttpFoundation\Response::HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR`